# Do chemical reactions occur inside of the Shock wave?

Tags: aerodynamics, navier-stokes, shock-waves

I am currently reading Anderson's book on hypersonic aerodynamics. In the energy Navier-Stokes equations its is very common to ignore Dufour effect, which is (as I understand) non-negligible when huge density gradient exists. "Wait a sec" - I thought - "But there are huge density discontinuity across bow sw". Therefore, Dufour effect should be important inside of the SW if there are chemical reactions accuring. But do they? In the textbook it is assumed that chem reactions and ionization only happen inside of a shock layer.

Comment: Most explosions caused by humans are initiated with a chemical reaction, i.e., it is the sudden transformation of chemical energy into random kinetic energy (i.e., heat) that results in the initial blast wave that steepens into a shock wave.  Otherwise, the only shocks that would sufficiently heat the gas to cause ionization are those in strong hypersonic shocks.  I am not sure about chemical reactions...